# Windows Forms Labels not showing before continuing

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, hide, show

I'm building a simple Forms project. The method that loads the data takes a while to run, so I want the window to show that it is loading. There are some Labels that I Hide when the Form loads and then Show when the data is loading. However, for some reason I can't figure out, my Labels do not Show. The Buttons Hide properly, but the Labels do not Show before the data starts loading. Why is this? How do I fix it? I am looking for the simplest solution possible, please and thanks.

```
private void loadExistingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadExistingButton.Hide();
            loadJsonButton.Hide();
            this.Size = new Size(375, 179);
            cardsLabel.Show();
            loadingLabel.Show();
            treeLabel.Show();
            formattedLabel.Show();

            loadFromExisting();
            MainForm mainForm = new MainForm(startNode);
            mainForm.FormClosed += (s, args) => this.Close();
            this.Hide();
            mainForm.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void StartForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cardsLabel.Hide();
            loadingLabel.Hide();
            treeLabel.Hide();
            formattedLabel.Hide();
        }
```

Comment: Try setting Visible property of labels instead of using hide and show method

Comment: Have you tried to call `Refresh()` before `loadFromExisting();`? -- @Chetan The `Show()` and `Hide()` methods of a Control just set the `Visible` property.

Comment: Changing to directly setting Visible did not solve the problem, however calling Refresh() after Show did solve the problem. Thank you @Jimi for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

@Chetan 's suggestion is more suitable.

for example

```
//you can use this
cardsLabel.Visible = true;
//instead of
cardsLabel.Show();

//and you can use this
cardsLabel.Visible = false;
//instead of
cardsLabel.Hide();
```

Comment: Did you read my comment? No? Then just take a look at the Source Code of [Control.Hide()](https://source.dot.net/#System.Windows.Forms/System/Windows/Forms/Control.cs,6247) and [Control.Show()](https://source.dot.net/#System.Windows.Forms/System/Windows/Forms/Control.cs,11393) -- You may notice that it's exact same thing. -- What you could suggest is why showing a Control that was hidden is not exactly the same thing as hiding a Control (that was of course previously visible). Check the Source Code, you'll find out.

Answer (score 0):

Changing to directly setting Visible did not solve the problem, however calling Refresh() after Show did solve the problem. Thank you @Jimi for the solution!